# Min heap without recursion

Tags: c++, algorithm, array, stream, heap

The code reads in integer array from user input and builds a minimum heap via an iterative scheme.
Are there any edge cases in which this approach would fail?

For the following test case/command sequence:

```
1 4 3 10 12 6 -1
remove
remove
print
```

My output is `4 6 10 12` instead of `4 10 6 12`, is this an invalid implementation?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <cmath>

int readheap(int* theheap) {
    std::string num;
    int val = 0;
    int size = 0;
    std::cout << "Enter the elements of heap" << std::endl;
    std::getline(std::cin, num);
    std::istringstream iss(num);    
    while (iss >> val) {
        if (val != ' ' && val > 0){
            theheap[size] = val;
            ++size;
        }
    }
    if(size <= 1) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Invalid user input");
    }

for (int k = 1; k < size; ++k) {

        if (theheap[k] > theheap[(k - 1) / 2])  { 
            int j = k; 

            while (theheap[j] > theheap[(j - 1) / 2])  { 
                std::swap(theheap[j], theheap[(j - 1) / 2]); 
                j = (j - 1) / 2; 
            }
        }
    }
    for (int k = size - 1; k > 0; --k) {
        std::swap(theheap[0], theheap[k]);           

        int j = 0, index; 

        do { 
            index = (2 * j + 1);  

            if (theheap[index] < theheap[index + 1] && index < (k - 1)) 
                ++index; 

            if (theheap[j] < theheap[index] && index < k) 
                std::swap(theheap[j], theheap[index]); 

            j = index; 

        } while (index < k); 
    } 
    std::cout << "Size of heap is " << size << '\n';
    return size;
}

void heapRemove(int* theheap, int& size) {
    for(int i=0; i<size-1; ++i){
        theheap[i] = theheap[i+1];
    }
    int* x = theheap;
    x = nullptr;
    delete x;
    size--; 
    for (int k = 1; k < size; ++k) {

        if (theheap[k] > theheap[(k - 1) / 2])  { 
            int j = k; 

            while (theheap[j] > theheap[(j - 1) / 2])  { 
                std::swap(theheap[j], theheap[(j - 1) / 2]); 
                j = (j - 1) / 2; 
            }
        }
    }
    for (int k = size - 1; k > 0; --k) {  
        std::swap(theheap[0], theheap[k]);      

        int j = 0, index; 

        do { 
            index = (2 * j + 1);  

            if (theheap[index] < theheap[index + 1] && index < (k - 1)) 
                ++index; 

            if (theheap[j] < theheap[index] && index < k) 
                std::swap(theheap[j], theheap[index]); 

            j = index; 

        } while (index < k); 
    }
}

void heapPrint(int* theheap, int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i){
        std::cout << theheap[i] << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main() {
    int* theheap = new int[10];
    int size = readheap(theheap);
    heapPrint(theheap, size);
    heapRemove(theheap, size);
    heapPrint(theheap, size);
    std::cout << size << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is this post about converting recursive code to iterative. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159590/way-to-go-from-recursion-to-iteration. You can convert a known algorithm.

Comment: Is a 1-element heap really invalid user input? (well, you asked for edge cases...)

Comment: I reversed the change you made to the code in [revision](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/revisions/240232/2) (i.e. `if(size < 1) `). Please do not update the code in your question. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see [_what you may and may not do after receiving answers_](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765).

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate, yes that should be if(size < 1).

Answer (score 2):

### Memory over-runs

`readheap` is non-size-aware, so it's wide open to an overrun error (or even a deliberate overrun attack). Pass in a size, or use a sized data structure like a `vector`.

### Indentation

You should fix it up for this line:

```
for (int k = 1; k < size; ++k) {
```

### Order-of-operations

Neither of these expressions need parentheses:

```
index = (2 * j + 1);  

index < (k - 1)
```

### Deleting a null?

```
x = nullptr;
delete x;
```

Does that actually run without crashing?

### Const arguments

```
void heapPrint(int* theheap, int size) {
```

should be

```
void heapPrint(const int *theheap, int size) {
```

Comment: The specific problem I'm solving requires the specific function signatures I utilized. No vectors, just pointers to integers.

Answer (score 2):

1. Explicit use of new and delete for memory management is old school and very very prone to memory leaks. Use containers like std::vector or std::array. In current code, you are leaking memory pointed by theheap pointer.
2. Function readheap is doing two things. Reading input from cin into array theheap and then converting theheap array into actual heap. Split it into separate functions. ReadInput and Heapify
3. To improve code readability, index operation like `theheap[(j - 1) / 2]` or `index = (2 * j + 1)` can be encapsulated in GetParent, GetLeftChild, GetRightChild like APIs.
4. Heapify in iterative mode can look like below. Please note switching from recursion from iteration shouldn't change code logic. Recursion vs iteration can be seen as embedding difference.

```
    void BuildHeap(std::vector<int>& theHeap)
    {
        for (int i = theHeap.size() / 2; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            Heapify(theHeap, i);
        }
    }

    void Heapify(std::vector<int>& theHeap, size_t index)
    {
       // Next three lines (stack and while loop) needed for converting recursion to iteration. If you remove these three lines and add recusrion call in place of callStack.push leaving other code unchanged, you will get recursive version of Heapify. 
        std::stack<int> callStack;
        callStack.push(index);
        while (!callStack.empty())
        {
            callStack.pop();
            size_t left = GetLeft(index);
            size_t right = GetRight(index);
            size_t smallest = index;
            if (left < theHeap.size() && theHeap[left] < theHeap[smallest])
                smallest = left;
            if (right < theHeap.size() && theHeap[right] < theHeap[smallest])
                smallest = right;

            if (smallest != index)
            {
                auto temp = m_buffer[index];
                m_buffer[index] = m_buffer[smallest];
                m_buffer[smallest] = temp;
                callStack.push(smallest); // Line needed for converting recursion to iteration
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The `std::floor` is unnecessary for integer division.

Comment: @L.F. Yes...my bad..correcting it

Comment: The specific problem I'm solving requires the function signatures I utilized. No vectors, just pointers to integers.

Answer (score 1):

## The heapRemove algorithm

`heapRemove` appears to remove the root element from the heap. However, it implements some sort of combination of ["bubble up"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Insert) (applied to every element) and ["bubble down"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Extract) (also applied to every element). That's extreme overkill, and turns what should be an O(log n) operation into an O(n log n) operation - that's not good.

Maybe the reason your code works that way, is that your solution for removing the root element was shifting every element down by one position. Don't do that, it already costs O(n) time just to do that, and it breaks the heap property to an unncessary degree so it takes a lot of work to restore the heap. The usual (and fast) solution is taking the *last* element of the heap and drop it into `theHeap[0]`, then bubble down from the root until the heap property is restored.

## `readheap`

`readheap` mixes IO and algorithms, when possible I recommend separating them, and it is possible here. `readheap` also mixes tons of bubble up and bubble down, which is again overkill. Pick one strategy and use it, not both. Applying bubble up to each element results in an O(n log n) heap construction algorithm, applying bubble down [in a particular way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Building_a_heap) can give you an O(n) heap construction algorithm.